# Как в LinuxMint Mate отключить всплывающие подсказки?

Tags: linux

Постоянные всплывающие подсказки возле курсора как отключить?

Comment: Решено.
Ссылка на решение http://xubuntu-ru.net/how-to/141-kak-otklyuchit-vsplyvayuschie-podskazki-v-xubuntu-1310.html

Comment: оформите, пожалуйста, как ответ, приведя не только ссылку, но и всё решение.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать в домашнем каталоге файл с названием .gtkrc-2.0
Записать в этот файл "gtk-enable-tooltips = 0" без кавычек и завершить сеанс.